# how to stitch two tkinter windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I need to stitch two or more tkinter windows together, so that if one window moves, the other windows moves together. This will give an impression that there is only one window open and in focus rather than showing multiple windows. I tried to read and find an solution but no solution has directly addressed this issue. I acknowledge that using the Configure, we can detect the movement of the tkinter window and then bind a function can be used to stitch the open windows. But I am not able to do so. Below is my code so far:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("350x300+200+100") 

def opennewwindow():
    newWindow = Toplevel(root)
    newWindow.geometry("350x300+200+100") 
def move(event=None):
    w = root.winfo_width()
    h = root.winfo_height()
    x = root.winfo_x()
    y = root.winfo_y()    
    root.geometry("%ix%i+%i+%i" % (w, h, x, y))

button = tk.Button(root, text = "button", command=opennewwindow)
button.place(width=160,   height=70, x=24, y=100)
root.bind("<Configure>", move)
root.mainloop()
```

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you call `root.withdraw()`? If you want to display it again you can call `root.deiconify()`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what You were looking for:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("350x300+200+100")
tp = None


def open_new_window():
    global tp
    tp = Toplevel(root)


def move(event=None):
    if tp is None:
        return
    w = root.winfo_width()
    h = root.winfo_height()
    x = root.winfo_x()
    y = root.winfo_y()
    tp.geometry(f"{w}x{h}+{x}+{y}")


button = tk.Button(root, text="button", command=open_new_window)
button.place(width=160,   height=70, x=24, y=100)
root.bind("<Configure>", move)
root.mainloop()
```

I couldn't yet think of how to do this without using global, if You have questions ask